# Do Yahoo FF yardage bonuses stack?

Tags: espn-fantasy-football

Yahoo Fantasy Football, let's say we set bonuses for rushing yardage at 150 - 1, 200 - 2, 250 - 3.

If a player rushes for 250+ yards, does he get 3 bonus points or 6?

I don't have enough rep to use a correct tag.

Comment: perhaps you should ask it here: http://sports.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fantasy sports are in the weird limbo between gaming and sports but the sports SE looks like it's just about discussing the actual sports and not fantasy games based on them.

Comment: agreed, but there has already been a [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/are-fantasy-sports-considered-inside-of-our-scope) question about them and they were decided off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple bonuses are set, that player would get the combined point total. In your example if the player rushed for 250 yards, he would get all 6  points. If a player only rushed for 210 yards, he would get 3 points.

Here is an example from my current yahoo fantasy league (note the maximum points)

[image: Yahoo Example]